# AWS serverless dynamodb - deleting item not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I have deployed a serverless app to aws with serverless framework. I have a simple todo application.

TodoItem looks like this:

```
export interface TodoItem {
  userId: string
  todoId: string
  createdAt: string
  name: string
  dueDate: string
  done: boolean
  attachmentUrl?: string
}
```

This is how I have set up the dynamodb:

```
TodosDynamoDBTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: todoId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: todoId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.USER_ID_INDEX}
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: userId
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: createdAt
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
```

My delete todo lambda function looks like this:

```
export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  const todoId = event.pathParameters.todoId

  logger.info('Event: ', event)
  logger.info('Deleting a todo with id: ', todoId)
  // TODO: Remove a TODO item by id
  await deleteTodo(todoId, getUserId(event))

  return {
    statusCode: 204,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    body: null
  }
}
```

And I am deleting an item like this:

```
async deleteTodo(todoId: string, userId: string): Promise<any> {
    await this.docClient
      .delete({
        TableName: this.todosTable,
        Key: {
          userId,
          todoId
        }
      })
      .promise()
  }
```

But, when I am try to delete an item I get:

> 502 Bad Gateway

In cloudwatch logs I can see that I get this error:

> 2020-10-12T08:43:45.648Z 7ff99035-bf3d-4158-b311-1e6d7e73a6e5 ERROR
> Invoke Error {"errorType":"ValidationException","errorMessage":"The
> provided key element does not match the
> schema","code":"ValidationException","message":"The provided key
> element does not match the
> schema","time":"2020-10-12T08:43:45.629Z","requestId":"SRSL15PC9C3BN4RC4F5K3ERFNNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":49.16692204166978,"stack":["ValidationException:
> The provided key element does not match the schema"," at
> constructor.httpResponse
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:47:1)","
> at constructor.shift [as callListeners]
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:100:1)","
> at constructor.doneCallback [as emit]
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:75:1)","
> at constructor.call [as emitEvent]
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:1)","
> at constructor.emit
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:1)","
> at r.call [as runTo]
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:1)","
> at runTo
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:1)","
> at constructor.done
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:1)","
> at constructor.call
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:1)","
> at constructor.Error [as callListeners]
> (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:108:1)"]}

I am suspecting that I have set up hash and range keys for the dynamodb table wrongly. I am not sure what is the correct way to set this up for such table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table definition, the key consists of `todoId` and `createdAt`. Your delete function however uses `todoId` along with `userId` as key. This doesn’t work.

I’m not sure why you need the user ID when you already have the todo ID which I would assume to be unique. Does it work if you simply remove the `userId` from the `Key` attribute in the delete parameter object like this?

```
async deleteTodo(todoId: string, userId: string): Promise<any> {
    await this.docClient
      .delete({
        TableName: this.todosTable,
        Key: {
          todoId
        }
      })
      .promise()
  }
```